# azure-macro-utils not present in rootfs when adding meta-iot-cloud to bitbake

Tags: c, yocto, bitbake, azure-iot-sdk, arm-linux

I added the meta-iot-cloud layer to bitbake and updated the `local.conf` file with:

```
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "packagegroup-cloud-azure"
```

bitbake runs successfully and everything except the `azure-macro-utils-c` is in the rootfs, though there is a recipe for this.

I added this layer in order to cross-compile the `azure-iot-sdk-c` and use the `iothub_client` in my application running on arm cpu. Because the macro utils are missing, I cannot include the client code in my project. Is there a better way to go about this or a way to make sure all dependencies will be in the include path on the rootfs?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to cross-compile it locally and import it in the project using:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/doc/Docker_SDK_Cross_Compile.md

while doing so, I used newer versions of openssl and curl.

Comment: Did you manage to use this with a recent Yocto release?

I think that the meta-iot-cloud is somewhat broken. I got DNS errors when I used the output with example code.